# Is it possible to monitor "Full GC" frequency in JMX (on HotSpot)?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, monitoring, jmx, jvm-hotspot

I want to monitor Full GC frequency in JMX. A MBean exposes GC count.
(cf. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html  -   java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=).

The problem is that MBean does not distinguish between minor and full gc.

Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks.

Arnault

Comment: you may find that the old gen usage before/after gc decreases only for full gc.  If this is the case for you, then that will be sufficient to identify full gc's.

Comment: [This might be able to give you some insight](https://gist.github.com/khotyn/1520947) into which type of GC is enabled on your JVM where you are testing your code

Answer (score 9):

I'm not completely sure about this but I assume that the garbage collector that controls all the memory pools (at least the one for Old Gen) is the one used for major gc. e.g.: I have a JVM running with these 2 collectors:

- PS MarkSweep

  - MemoryPoolNames: PS Eden Space, PS Survivor Space, PS Old Gen, PS Perm Gen
  - CollectionCount: 68
- PS Scavenge

  - MemoryPoolNames: PS Eden Space, PS Survivor Space
  - CollectionCount: 2690

Taking this into account I would say, PS Scavenge is used for minor gc and PS MarkSweep for major gc.

UPDATE (based on @ajeanson comment, thanks for your feedback btw):

Effectively, the example I put in there was taken from the information exposed in the MXBeans of the JVM I was using. As you mentioned, these are GC algorithms, and the name the MXBean for the GC is using is based on the algorithm the GC is using. I've been looking for some more information about this; in this article http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html, reads the following:

> The Java HotSpot VM defines two
>   generations: the young generation
>   (sometimes called the "nursery") and
>   the old generation. The young
>   generation consists of an "Eden space"
>   and two "survivor spaces." The VM
>   initially assigns all objects to the
>   Eden space, and most objects die
>   there. When it performs a minor GC,
>   the VM moves any remaining objects
>   from the Eden space to one of the
>   survivor spaces. The VM moves objects
>   that live long enough in the survivor
>   spaces to the "tenured" space in the
>   old generation. When the tenured
>   generation fills up, there is a full
>   GC that is often much slower because
>   it involves all live objects. The
>   permanent generation holds all the
>   reflective data of the virtual machine
>   itself, such as class and method
>   objects.

Taking a look at the collectionCount property on the MXBeans, in the case of my "PS MarkSweep" collector (the one managing the Old Generation pool), the collection count seems to increase only when I get a full GC in the verbose output. I might be wrong and maybe in some cases this Collector performs also minor GC, but I would need to run more tests to be totally sure about this.
Please, let me know if someone finds out something else or you have some more specific information about this issue as I'm quite interested in it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post but IMHO, they are two diffrent GC algorithms implementations and for those GC you can have minor or major collections. I made a test looking at verbose GC and I can see some "Full GC" but only CollectionCount incerementation in my MBeans.

Answer (score 0):

it does ... have a look to the names e.g. ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep, .. etc.
some names are for minor gc, some for full gc,

Comment: Sorry, but not exactly. ParNew and ConcurrentMarkSweep are GC algorithms implementations and for those GC you can have minor or major collection.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the same information and found out after reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BABFAFAE for JAVA 8 that some collectors can be used for both minor/full GCs (such as G1 or SerialGC) but some other collectors are for only minor or full GCs (such as ParNewGC, ConcMarkSweepGC).

And when you use the G1 for example, the two collectors used are quite explicit with their names and the one for full gc is the G1 Old Generation.

But, because the MXBean is missing the information about being minor or full, either:

- you know the GC in use for your app and code accordingly your monitoring method knowing the collector names
- or you start having like a map of all possibilities for your selected JVM version

I will, in my case, just print the collector name along with the time and count value and let the person reading those data make the analysis. In my case, the data will be graphed (Grafana)

Not sure if the newest JDK improve this...